# ubuntu builder alternative or replacement

Tags: software-recommendation

Does anyone know a good replacement or an alternative for the discontinued ubuntu builder ? I 've been looking for a sollution to customize a 14.04 live cd but i haven't succeded.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Customization Kit

Here is a tutorial:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization