# Does Ubuntu 14.10 support Ubuntu builder?

Tags: 14.10

I was looking into remastering ubuntu and this one seems promising so will it work?

Comment: Do be aware that support for 14.10 ends in July of this year. It might be more fruitful to remaster a 15.04 or 14.04 version.

Comment: Ok I will install 15.04...

Answer (score 2):

The question needs to be reversed: does Ubuntu Builder support Ubuntu 14.10

And the answer is probably no since Ubuntu Builder was discontinued around 2014-02-12 or it might be yes, with limited support. [ubuntu builder alternative or replacement](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451572/ubuntu-builder-alternative-or-replacement) suggests Ubuntu Customization Kit

Might I offer a solution that will always work? Use the manual method and forget about tools like Ubuntu Builder. It will teach you a lot about the inner workings of an operating system and it will also make it possible for you to investigate alterations you want to make where a tool like Ubuntu Builder will restrict you to what the tool can offer.

I have written an example based of Ubuntu Server: [How to create a Customized Ubuntu Server ISO?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409607/how-to-create-a-customized-ubuntu-server-iso) That will allow you to pick your own desktop or desktops if you want more than 1. Or make your own server based install. Imagine a live dvd with apache, mysql, php pre-installed but also that website you made all ready to go from the Live DVD with a shortcut on the desktop to that website and/or pre-made documents about that website.

And we also have [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd) that is about editing an Ubuntu with already a desktop in the Live DVD.

Comment: I am using 14.10 by the way would like to use 15.04 instead of 14.10 so I will have systemd without having to add it...

Comment: Is there a way to do this without server?